# Header line break in Rmarkdown, change textsize after, included as a whole in TOC

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I want a header line break in Rmarkdown, after the break the text should appear smaller (it's the subtitle). The guy should appear in the table of contents as a whole (rather with author's name). 
Here's my attempt where only the header appears in the TOC:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# This is the header
\vspace{-4mm}

**This should be the subtitle after the line-break**

\vspace{2mm}

*Author's Name*

\vspace{10mm}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
````

Desired outcome something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think LaTeX might give you more options for what you'd like here. In LaTeX, you can you "\\" to create a line break almost anywhere in the code. Then, to get the TOC left-aligned like in your example output, you can use the "tocloft" package and set the indentation for subsections with "\cftsetindents{subsection}{0in}{0in}".

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{tocloft}
---
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0in}{0in}

\hypertarget{toc}{}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\section{Header}

\subsection[Subtitle \\ \emph{Author's Name}]{Subtitle \\\\ \normalfont{\emph{Author's Name}}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit:**

If you want to remove the page number from being added to the "\section" names in the TOC (i.e. "Header" in this case), then there's a two-step solution I know of: (1) you can add an asterisk (*) between "\section" and the name of the section "{Header}" to exclude that section from being listed in the TOC; (2) then you can add the bold-font name of the section into the related subsection portion of the TOC (again using \\ for line breaks) so that the section name appears in the TOC by name only, not number.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, but throw's me a **! LaTeX Error: \l@chapter undefined.**

Comment: No problem. Errors in LaTeX are typically from minor changes. Are you getting the error after copy/pasting exactly what's above or after adding to the script? If the second case is true, please provide the updated script you're working with so that I can try to reproduce and solve the error.

Comment: I've now verified that the above script works as displayed on both MacOS with LaTeX and Windows OS with MiKTeX. I unfortunately haven't been able to reproduce the error mentioned. Are you using a different operating system (OS) or LaTeX version than those mentioned? Or is it possible there are more packages/software that needs to be updated or downloaded for set-up? Sometimes these types of errors are from something so small as a missing bracket '}' or sometimes an apostrophe that's copy/pasted ends up with a different font/encoding than the rest of the script and breaks the code.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I have copied your code again and checked for encoding errors, all packages are update. I am using Win 7 64 pro SP 1, R64 version 3.4.1, RStudio64 Version 1.0.153 and MiKTeX. First run of your code prompted me to install tocloft package as expected. Still same error as mentioned - weird.

Comment: In a situation like this, sometimes it can be helpful to code and test incrementally to sift out an error. I'd recommend starting with the most basic pieces of the above script that you're confident will work, and then slowly add a line, run the code; add another line, rerun the code, etc. Occasionally, and especially with a script this short, that can be the most efficient way to at least find the cause of the error. Then we can work from there once we have more specific information.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply due to a vacation. I tried your code again on my home machine - and it worked just fine and I want to thank you a lot! (Actually I don't see a difference in my installations but such things happen.) Do you see a chance to avoid the page number after "Header"? It would look even nicer.

Comment: @jaySf - No problem. You're very welcome. I've also made an edit above which adds an option to exclude the \section number ("Header" number) from the TOC.

Comment: So I changed the code concerned to `\subsection[\textbf{Header} \\ Subtitle \\ \emph{Author's Name}]{Subtitle \\\\ \normalfont{\emph{Author's Name}}}` and it's working great, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The closes you're going to get what you want with markdown will be to use subtitles and sub-subtitles (they map to h2 or h3 in html respecitvely).

```
# This is the header

## This should be the subtitle after the line-break

### *Author's Name*

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

With the default template you get:

[image]

If you want more control over the layout, you should tweak your [pandoc LaTeX template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates).

Comment: That's the Rmd basics - okay! For the clarity: in the meanwhile I help myself with a native `# Header`, then each addition - the subtitle (bold) and the author (italic) - in new lines afterwards. With a little LaTeX spacing it looks pretty good at the beginning of my paper. In the TOC then only the header appears then - sure. The great drawback of your suggested solution is the page-numbering of the additions. However, thanks for your link for pandoc LaTeX template tweaking!